# Is there a syntax for adding wikipedia links?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

For example:

```
(wiki)[Deinococcus radiodurans]
```

because normally I must do it this way:

```
[Deinococcus radiodurans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinococcus_radiodurans)
```

[Deinococcus radiodurans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinococcus_radiodurans)

Comment: There isn’t – there should be.

Comment: Syntax could be even so simple as `[[Deinococcus radiodurans]]` that.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not supported by the editor and I doubt it will be supported in the future.

I'd also like to encourage users to cite scientific journals, making it easier to cite Wikipedia runs somewhat counter to that purpose.